# Use squeeze theorem to find the limit of a non-trigonometric (rational) function

Tags: calculus, limits

> Use the squeeze theorem to prove $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2x^3}{x+1} =0$$

The only thing I can think of is that for all $x<0$  $f(x) $will be negative and positive for all $x>0$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}-x \le \frac {2x^3}{x+1} \le x$$

and then substitute $x$ proving $\lim_{x \to 0} -x = \lim f(x) = \lim x$.

Is this valid or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you know the usual operations on limits? This is $0\over1$, which is simply 0.

Comment: Yes that I know but the question in the exercise is stated to use the squeeze theorem

Comment: Ok, just making sure :) The answer is below, so no need to add anything to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $ x \in (-1, 1)\setminus \{0\} $

$$ x^3 = \dfrac{2x^3}{2} =  \dfrac{ 2x^3}{ 1 + 1}  \le \frac{2x^3}{x + 1} \le \frac{2x^3}{x} = 2x^2 $$

And $$ \lim_{x \to 0}x^3 = \lim_{x \to 0}2x^2 = 0  $$